# Rails 3 cancan authorize image display

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I'm using rails 3 with cancan for authorization in one of our applications and I wanted to add authorize condition for the image tag.

Please note that I don't want to create a custom action just to authorize image access.

Please suggest what can be the best way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle this without using a controller.

1. Add a role to the user model that has "view image" capability. Then wrap the image tag with a `can?` condition in the view.
2. Add all image assets to the database and test if an asset is associated with the user and can be read.